# How to iterate over a const vector<glm::vec3>

Tags: c++

I have this vector of glm::vec3 elements

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> const& vertices
```

and i want to iterate over them. I tried it like this..

```
for(std::vector<glm::vec3>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {
        ...  
}
```

.. but the compiler is telling me

```
no viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<pointer>'
```

Can anyone help me how to iterate properly over this vector. Thank You :)

Comment: If you think it is a problem with `glm::vec3`, try with `int`.

Comment: oh thanks thats a good idea. Sadly i am a real beginner to c++

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because you declared the std::vector as constant:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> const& vertices
```

Then when you declared a loop of iterators you used mutable iterators (i.e. non-constant iterators which allow you to write to the values pointed to by the iterator).  This is in direct violation to your original declaration of the vector.  You can fix this by using a constant iterator to do the loop as such:

```
for(std::vector<glm::vec3>::const_iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it) {
    ...  
}
```

Or if you do require mutating access (i.e. you want to write to the data) by declaring the original declaration of the vector without the "const" keyword as such:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was a really stupid error. Sadly i am no experienced c++ programmer but i had to do this exercise :D